# Dampen spin on Matterjs circle body

Tags: game-physics, matter.js

I made a bunch of circles, and reduced their bounciness by setting restitution to 0.3, but sometimes they rotate wildly, I was wondering what I should alter to dampen rotation quicker.

```
  var circle = Bodies.circle(500, -100, 20, {
    restitution: 0.3,
    render: {
     sprite: {
        texture: randomPopcorn()
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What parameters you set depends on what result you want.

- If you want want objects to be slowed down more over time then increase 
  `frictionAir` from its default of `0.01`.
- If you just want reduced spinning from the get-go without changing their linear 
  movement then set `inertia` to something large.
- If you don't think changing just the inertia looks realistic then increase 
  `density` from `0.001`.